# Grafana config volume mapping not working while running from Docker

Tags: docker, grafana

1) I am running Grafana v6.7.2 from Docker.

2) I wanted to enable grafana log. Since I am running from Docker, /etc/grafana/grafana.ini is read only

3) Now, cloned that grafana.ini to my host where docker is running from. I un-commented this line to enabling logging: `logs = /var/log/grafana`

```
#################################### Paths ####################################
[paths]
# Path to where grafana can store temp files, sessions, and the sqlite3 db (if that is used)
;data = /var/lib/grafana

# Temporary files in `data` directory older than given duration will be removed
;temp_data_lifetime = 24h

# Directory where grafana can store logs
logs = /var/log/grafana
```

4) I made sure to stop Grafana container. Then, issued following command to to re-start Grafana. This time it has volume mapping for config:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -v "$PWD/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini" -v grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana grafana_internal:latest
```

5) I made sure Grafana container running, and I can access the UI

6) Then, I went here to see if log is generated: `/var/log/grafana/` using `docker exec <yourimage> ls /var/log/grafana`

The issue is that there was no Grafana log. Now, this led me to believe config volume mapping may not be working as expected.

Any pointers would be helpful.

thanks.

Comment: Where exactly are you looking for `/var/log/grafana`? That directory would only exist *inside* your container (e.g., you could see it using `docker exec <yourimage> ls /var/log/grafana`). You haven't mapped a host directory to that path.

Comment: Not in host. I looked inside container: docker exec <yourimage> ls /var/log/grafana.

Comment: If you look at `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` inside your container (again using `docker exec`), that should answer your question w/r/t to whether volume mapping is working or not. I suspect it's working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the running `grafana` instance using e.g. `ps`, you'll see this:

```
$ ps -fe | grep grafana
    1 grafana   0:00 grafana-server --homepath=/usr/share/grafana --config=/etc/grafana/grafana.ini --packaging=docker cfg:default.log.mode=console cfg:default.paths.data=/var/lib/grafana cf
g:default.paths.logs=/var/log/grafana cfg:default.paths.plugins=/var/lib/grafana/plugins cfg:default.paths.provisioning=/etc/grafana/provisioning
```

If you take a close look at those config options, you'll see:

```
cfg:default.log.mode=console
```

That means that Grafana will log only to the console. You can inspect these logs using `docker logs`. There's not really any reason to have Grafana log to a file also (or instead of).

If you really want Grafana to log to a file, you need to include the following in your `grafana.ini`:

```
[log]
mode = console file
```

With this in my `grafana.ini`, I see output on the docker console and I see logs in `/var/log/grafana/grafana.log`.

But like I said, I don't see any point in create the logfile when you can capture the same information from `docker logs`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. My `grafana.ini` had `mode = console file` commented out which is default.